# How to close popup window using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium to login into `Way2sms` , Here you should look into my source code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

     WebDriver driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();

     driver.get("http://site25.way2sms.com/content/index.html");

     driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("9982XXXX");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");

     driver.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();

     System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

  }

}
```

But there is a problem with `way2sms`. It opens some pop ups with advertisement. So please help, How to login it.. I'm unable to login it due to advertisement `pop ups`.

*surely, help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 1):

In order to close other windows you can switch between windows and close the unwanted ones. you can try below sample code:

```
    getWebElement(webDriver, How.ID, getValueFromKey("helpLinkID"))
                .click();
        Set s = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator ite = s.iterator();
        String previousWindow = "";
        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            String popupHandle = ite.next().toString();
            webDriver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
            String currentURL = webDriver.getCurrentUrl();
            if ((currentURL.contains("/webhelp/Login.htm"))) {
                webDriver.close();

                webDriver.switchTo().window(previousWindow);

            }
            previousWindow = popupHandle;
        }
```

Comment: Thats is not the exact code you need, you need to make required modifications as per your windows. You can debug and check where exactly it is failing

Comment: Dude, Do you know any method to hide `firefox` when you use `Firefox` driver? Please let me know if you know..

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach using Firefox,I observed only one window is getting open every time so i used window-handle to close the open window and its working.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
String Parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle( );
     driver.get("http://site25.way2sms.com/content/index.html");
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));
     for ( String currentwindow : driver.getWindowHandles())  
          driver.switchTo( ).window(currentwindow);  
               {  

                 driver.close( );  
               }  

               driver.switchTo().window(Parentwindow);  
     driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("9982XXXX");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");

     driver.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
```

Comment: Dude.. I tried your source code .. but it's saying `Session is closed`

Comment: With which driver are you trying ? FirefoxDriver or HtmlUnitDriver?  If using HTMLUnitDriver then can you try using FirefoxDriver?

Comment: `Htmlunitdriver` dude.... But i don't want to appear firefox.. So i'm using Htmlunitdriver.

Comment: Do you know any method to hide `firefox` when you use that `firefox` driver?

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning 'hide' firefox? and what is the reason behind using HTMLunitDriver ?

Comment: When you use firefox driver, It means.. After running your program, your firefox will appear and do that task what you write in your program. But i want to hide my Firefox by using firefox driver. Is it possible in your concern? If yes, Please let me know ? dude..

Comment: I am sorry if I understand you incorrectly, but is that fine with you if Firefox browser  kept  minimized while running your test? We cannot completely hide the browser instance but we can minimized it.

Comment: Here i get stuck.. :( Sorry but i can't minimize it..  :( Sorry!

Comment: I have updated my code above, Please let me know if it serves your purpose?

Comment: Dude, Still getting the same error `Session is closed!` I think it is because you're using `driver.close()` that's why i'm getting this error.. :(

Comment: Can you use firefoxdriver? i have updated it again in the code.

Comment: Here's how you can run [Firefox headless](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/04/headless-tests-with-firefox-webdriver.html)

Comment: @VivekSingh : Thank you so much, In-fact i was looking for the session closed issue with HTMLUnitDriver, But yes it will definitely help this situation where he want to run Firefox headless, Helpful comment vote from me, Thanks again